Should I use both HtmlEncode and JavaScriptStringEncode if inside HTML <script> tag to create HtmlString from string?
My question is very similar to this one, but without the <% %> details.
Let's say I have the following code:
public static IHtmlString AddSomethingToWindow(string value) {
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            output.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            output.Append("window.something=\"" + value + "\";");
            output.Append("</script>");
            return new HtmlString(output.ToString());
}

Let's say value is coming from an untrusted source & could be anything.
To make RenderSomething method safe, do I need HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value)) or is just HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value) sufficient? Or are both wrong?

Simplest thing would be a JSON encoder, because valid JSON is valid JavaScript (and it's safe).

encoding does not change anything in regards to some script security - script is script, and by encoding it, you do not change the security aspect here at all, just that funny characters such as spaces etc. can be correctly encoded. So, if you encode un-safe script, well, then you have some unsafe script. So, encoding really has little to do with security issues, only that of having some encoded script that will work.

@AlbertD.Kallal I've updated the question to make it clearer. Please, take a look at edit history. The purpose here is to include value as part of a JS string, not include it as any JS code.

@Pointy I upvoted the comment, but after thinking I think this is not correct. If the JSON has a string that has "", it'll cause issues, I think.

"Let's say value is coming from an untrusted source & could be anything." <- then you shouldn't be injecting this as a script.

@ControlAltDel I don't want to inject it as a script. I want to inject it as part of a JS string. E.g., window.something="really-dangerous-value";. Whatever really-dangerous-value is, I want my code to work correctly.

@HossamEl-Deen re: "I don't want to..." then why in this string you are creating are you injecting this inside a script tag?

@ControlAltDel The end-goal is to pass data from the view model in ASP.NET to JavaScript code.

@HossamEl-Deen not correct: a proper JSON serializer always renders "/" as "/"

@HossamEl-Deen Whatever your end goal, this introduces a huge vulnerability. In the business world you'd either need to find another (safer) way to achieve what you are doing or get rid of this functionality all together. Have you considered using a Wiki flavor?

@Pointy I stand corrected. I hereby confirm what you've said, negating what I've said before, for future readers. In the spec, it's seemingly not a must, but spec possibly says it's optional & as you've said typical JSON serializers do it. So, for future readers: try out your serialization library & see.

@ControlAltDel I'm not sure what you mean by Wiki flavor, but I generally agree with you that this is not ideal. However, there are other constraints in play, and according to my answer below it's possible to make it safe -- even if it's generally not recommended.

I strongly believe, although I'm not 100% sure, that JavaScriptStringEncode is enough.
(1) From HTML spec:

The easiest and safest way to avoid the rather strange restrictions described in this section is to always escape an ASCII case-insensitive match for "<!--" as "\x3C!--", "<script" as "\x3Cscript", and "</script" as "\x3C/script"...

(2) The core idea of this is supported by answers from other people 1 & 2, even though they may not be fully accurate or up to date with the spec comment above (from which the second linked answer is actually derived).
(3) Looking at JavaScriptStringEncode, it seemingly replaces <, among other characters, which should satisfy (1).


From these 3 points, I think one can conclude that calling JavaScriptStringEncode is enough, since the code inside script doesn't need to be HTML encoded, it just needs to escape <!--, <script, and </script (case-insensitively), which JavaScriptStringEncode by escaping < (replacing it with its Unicode sequence).

This is true. The HTML parser will pay absolutely no attention to the content of the <script> tag other than to scan for "". Thus, HTML encoding is not necessary is there is no HTML parsing involved.
